# Type German special characters with Bluetooth Keyboard

Tags: keyboard, external-keyboard, text-layout

I'm trying to type German special characters ä, ü, ß with Bluetooth keyboard (Logitech k810) using SwiftKey (this is the keyboard app I normally use when not using the keyboard, ideally wouldn't have to swap keyboards everytime). When typing directly onto the phone, I would long press the 'a' key to bring up the ä character, but doing the same thing on the physical keyboard just repeats the same character.
On my Windows laptop, I use Autohotkey to overide the input such that pressing CAPS + a = ä. Would be ideal to be able to do the same thing on android

Comment: You should be able to set the keyboard layout of your keyboard in the settings (e.g. Languages & Input).